# PHP: Как мне сравнить тип char с типом string?

Tags: php, массивы, char

Мне необходимо циклом перебрать строку и преобразовать кириллицу в латиницу:

```
<?php

$your_string = "дом";    
$array = str_split($your_string);     
foreach ($array as $char) 
{
  if ($char == "д")
  {
     echo "d";
  }
  elseif ($char == "о") 
  {
     echo "o";
  }
  elseif ($char == "м") 
  {
     echo "m";
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для мультибайтных строк надо использовать **[mb_str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-str-split.php)** и вообще те функции, которые начинаются с `mb_`

---

А вообще для решения задачи достаточно создать сразу ассоциативный массив вида:

```
['а' => 'a', 'б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v', ...]
```

и брать значение по ключу, вместо всяких иф элс

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, Алексей, как использовать mb_str_split? Я получаю ошибку: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_str_split()

Comment: @МаксимЗакревский скорее всего не установлено расширение PHP для работы с мультибайтовыми строками (или оно закоментировано в php.ini). Надо либо в php.ini найти и раскоментить в секции extensions  что-то наподобии `php_mbstring`.  Либо установить. Установка в зависимости от ОС и инструментов - разная.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!